# What is a good and what is the maximum amout of keys to delete with Redis DEL?

Tags: php, redis, predis

With [Redis DEL command](https://redis.io/commands/del) it is possible to delete multiple keys at a time. I am using PHP's [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) Redis client and I am wondering what is a good and what is the maximum amount of keys to delete within one call?

Comment: You're free to delete as many keys as you want, as long as your app can tolerate the lockup. Keyword: "your app".

Comment: Thanks! And lockup depend on the amount of keys in the database + the hardware performance? Or are there additional factors?

Comment: Amount of keys being deleted, plus your server's performance, yes.

Comment: So it would be better to run multiple DEL commands with a pipeline after each other than running a big one, so that other operations might be executed inbetween?

Comment: Yep, a batch of smaller DEL requests will be run much smoother.